# GATE annotation extraction

Tags: gate

I have used GATE to annotate the documents and saved the out put in XML. I need all the entities with relations to be extracted to csv file, can anyone please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by excecuting this recipe in pipeline

```
new File("../outfile.csv").withWriterAppend{ out ->doc.getAnnotations().each {anno ->
  if( anno.getFeatures() )
    anno.getFeatures().each{ fName, fValue ->
      out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},"${fName}","${fValue}"/)
    }
  else
    out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},,/)        
}}
```